# How to remove iframe src in a text?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error when remove a iframe but can't remove tag p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999584/error-when-remove-a-iframe-but-cant-remove-tag-p)

I have a sample code:

```
$content = '<p><iframe width="640" scrolling="no" height="150" frameborder="1" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://test.html"></iframe></p><p>Hello world</p>';
$text = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe src="http://test.html" .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '', $content);
echo $text;
```

How to fix to remove this iframe result is: `<p>Hello world</p>`

Comment: Being unversed with regex, you should avoid it for such tasks. A traversal frontend to the DOM functions would be advisable. With QueryPath for example: `qp($html)->find("iframe[src=http://test.html]")->remove()->top()->html()`

Comment: The `iframe` in the `$content` is not closed. If it's not a typo, I think a regex might be better...`/<p>\s*<iframe(.*?)></p>/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = preg_replace('|<iframe [^>]*(src="http://test.html")[^>]*|', '', $content);
```